# How to get the mysql database relationship diagram

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, diagram

I have a Mysql database for my website which it is not made by me 
is there is any way to get the relationship diagram for this Database

Comment: Please try to state your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I know if you use xampp, you can go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin then click on the database you want then if you click designer near the top right it will have one done for you.

Comment: Yea but it doesn't show the relationship it just show the tables only

Comment: It does if you open the menu at the side and click toggle relation lines, you can also export the scheme just below it. hope this helps

Comment: bro i just tried it but it does not show the relation lines i tried another Database and the seam does not show the relations lines

Answer (score -1):

Tools which allow drawing ER Diagrams often can do this reverse-engineering for you - think MS Visio has such a feature, and also Visual Paradigm should do this for you. Also check [this link](http://www.gidf.de/er%20diagram%20software)!!

Comment: this tools will allow me to draw a ERD

Comment: i want to know the relationship between the tables so i ask for a way to generate the ER Diagram for this Database

Comment: question was " is there is any way to get the relationship diagram" - ahm, what's wrong with the answer how to get such an relationship diagram by using a software that does this by reverse-engineering from the ODBC data source? please clarify when downvoting.

Comment: check also here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d2e0fa48-9085-48ed-8efa-8a6cc2a083c5/reverse-engineer-in-visio-2013?forum=accessdev
and here (search for Reverse Engineer): 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Database-Model-also-known-as-Entity-Relationship-diagram-7042e719-384a-4b41-b29c-d1b35719fc93

Comment: i haven't did that and don't know who did downvoting

Comment: and i specified that i want to "get the relationship diagram for this database"

Comment: ok - in this case I hope the anwer helps :) with google you will also find alternative (open source) software that will do this for you...

Comment: Thanks i will try i have searched many times before i post this question but wasn't that specified at my search , excuse my english